# Have Local Notification Vibrate with no Text

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

I've got local notifications going off one after the other every second.  The text I'm using is just `@""`.  I register these notifications in `applicationWillResignActive`.  They do exactly what I want them to do when I background the app and either lock the iPhone or just leave it unlocked, which is vibrate with no banner showing up.  But when I lock the screen straight from the app, the local notifications that have `@""` as a text, it does not vibrate.

I have a timer that lasts 15 minutes to 24 hours.  I want the iPhone to vibrate every second for fifteen seconds while the app is in the background after locking the screen.  What I have now works only after press the home button, and/or lock the app, but not if I lock the screen straight from the app.

Answer (score 2):

There's no point in sending off a local notification with no text if all you want to do is vibrate the phone. Just call this method instead:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound( kSystemSoundID_Vibrate );
```

Comment: How can I do this when the app is not running?

Comment: I was thinking it'd be simpler if I just sent off a Local Notification instead of having to worry about doing things while the app is in the background.

Comment: Do you have backgrounding enabled? What is the purpose of these background vibrations?

Comment: Yes, I can do this in the background.  This seems like a worthless reason to use backgrounding in my app when I could use local notifications.  Using your method would be a much better approach while in the app obviously, as local notifications in-app simply call the application:didReceiveLocalNotification method.  But even if it does get past Apple's review (running app in background only to vibrate) I don't think it is worth doing this outside of the app.

Comment: How are you thinking you can send a local notification if the app is not running? Are you meaning a push notification?

Comment: No, not push, local.  Not [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but [UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  Yes I send them off when the app is running (when the app exits), but I only receive them when the app is not running.  I kill them if the app opens when the local notifications are still waiting to be displayed.

Comment: So i take it you're scheduling the fire date for a ways out? I dont really get what youre trying to accomplish. Maybe try to sum it up concisely?

Comment: I had edited the question a little earlier in response to your comment.  I appreciate the help, I tried your solution and it does the same thing as the local notification. :(  It vibrates only if I press home and wait for the time to run out.  The weird thing is, is if I run the app again with command R, while the vibrating "should" be happening, it vibrates every second, for both local and your way...  I don't know what is up.